# When the DLL file which include in Additional Dependencies under child floder,How can I find it

Tags: visual-c++

I Want Put those DLL files under a child folder.
the system is Win7 later.
like there is an opencv_world300d.dll , i need move it into my working directory (its  ./),but i want put it under child folder( i.e. ./DLL/) .
Does anyone Know about this ?

Comment: The OS does not look in that sub-directory.  There just isn't any point to it whatsoever.  So don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link specified describes [DLL search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications) on windows.

You can copy the opencv_world300d.dll in a sub-folder ( /DLL) but then you have to modify PATH environment variable to include new directory.

Comment: it.s long time to see this question, i slove the problem as MKR said . Thanks for MKR to answer . Best wishes